# Calling SharedPreferences, Intent and Retrofit without Activity

Tags: java, android

I am able to call Retrofit and SharedPreferences and Intent fine from an Activity and all works. But it gets messy real fast and lots of repetition thus I want to call them from a helper class instead. It makes it complicated cos I end up having to extend the Helper class with the Application class, followed by IDE complaining I have missing XML files which are actually not needed for a helper class.

Feel like I am over complicating things. What's the solution here? Write directly on Activity classes and endure the code repetitions or is there an elegant solution to this?

This is how I tried to extract the logic for Retrofit and Intent away from an Activity class Using a helper.

```
public class RetrofitHelper extends Application {

    private final String ERROR_MSG = "username is invalid";
    private static final String TAG = "RetrofitHelper";
    private static final String API_KEY = "";

    private VerificationHelper verificationHelper;

    public RetrofitHelper(VerificationHelper verificationHelper) {
        this.verificationHelper = verificationHelper;
    }

    public Retrofit getRetrofit(String baseUrl){
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(setTimeout())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        return builder.build();
    }

    public void performCallBack(Call<User> call){
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                String usernameToken = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getUsername();
                String username = null;
                if(usernameToken != null){
                    username = verificationHelper.parseToken(usernameToken, API_KEY);
                }
                if (username != null && !username.equals(ERROR_MSG)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Success " + username);
//                    verificationHelper.setPreferences(username);
                    verificationHelper.goToMainActivity();
                }
                else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Incorrect response.");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: server error");
            }
        });
    }

    private OkHttpClient setTimeout(){
        return new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
    }
}
```

For reference, VerificationHelper called from the above Helper.

```
public class VerificationHelper extends Application {

    private static boolean isValidCredential = false;

    public static boolean isValidCredential() {
        return isValidCredential;
    }

    static void setValidCredential(boolean validCredential) {
        isValidCredential = validCredential;
    }

    private <T> String convertObjToJson(T object){
        // some logic
        return "";
    }

    public String createToken(String apiKey, User user, long ttlMillis) {
        //some logic
        return "";
    }

    String parseToken(String token, String apiKey) {
        //some logic
        return "";
    }

    //trying to keep this here so I call at many places.
    void setPreferences(String username){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    //trying to keep this here so I call at many places.
    void goToMainActivity(){
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a Helper Class (no Activity extended) and pas the context to the functino that you want to call. An Exmaple with shared preferences:

```
public class SharedPreferenceHelper {

private final static String PREF_FILE = "<Shared_PReferences_Name>";

/**
 * Set a string shared preference
 * @param context - Context (Activity that is calling the function)
 * @param key - Key to set shared preference
 * @param value - Value for the key
 */
public static void setSharedPreferenceString(Context context, String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.apply();

}
}
```

The you can call the fucntino like this:

```
SharedPreferenceHelper.setSharedPreferenceString(MainActivity.this, <key>, <value>);
```

Source: https://github.com/nickescobedo/Android-Shared-Preferences-Helper/blob/master/SharedPreferenceHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)) you can see getDefaultSharedPreferences method takes a context as a parameter. This context can be an Activity, a Fragment or a Service. The simplest solution would be to pass the context to your helper class methods via dependency injection. Something like:

```java
void setUsernamePref(String username, Context context){
    SharedPreferences preferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username);
    editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Remember to avoid storing context statically in the helper class, otherwise you'll risk to fall into unwanted memory leaks